# MySQL: "Error creating table: Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql

I got 2 tables and i want to reference an id. The code is shown below. I get: "Error creating table: Cannot add foreign key constraint". I think thats becouse of auto increment. Can someone help? Cheers

```
$polls = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `polls` ( 
    `id_poll` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `descricao` VARCHAR(255), 
    `password` VARCHAR(255), 
    `privacidade` INT(1),   
    primary key (id_poll) 
    )";

if ($conn->query($polls) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table polls: CHECK!";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}


$options = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opcoes` ( 
    `id_opcao` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `id_poll` INT(10),
    `descricao` VARCHAR(255), 
    primary key (id_opcao),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_poll) REFERENCES polls(id_poll)
    )";

if ($conn->query($opcoes) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table opcoes: CHECK!";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: those two statements work for me.  is that the whole error you get back?

Comment: does the first table already exist when you run this?  does it exist exactly as stated in the code above?

Comment: I got it! id_poll needs to be NOT NULL on both tables. Ty

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it... provide some details and code for the next person who has this question.

Answer (score 0):

id_poll must be NOT NULL on both tables. Here's the code.

```
$polls = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `polls` ( 
    `id_poll` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `descricao` VARCHAR(255), 
    `password` VARCHAR(255), 
    `privacidade` INT(1),   
    primary key (id_poll) 
    )";

if ($conn->query($polls) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table polls: CHECK!";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}


$options = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opcoes` ( 
    `id_opcao` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `id_polls` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `descricao` VARCHAR(255), 
    primary key (id_opcao),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_polls) REFERENCES polls(id_poll)
    )";

if ($conn->query($options) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table opcoes: CHECK!";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
```